# materialize and jquery validation radio button

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

I am using the JQuery validation plugin to validate my HTML form. It works fine but when I use it to validate radio buttons, it is showing and error and the radio buttons are hidden and not showing until the user refreshes the page.

This is my code:

```
echo '<div class="col l6 s6">';
echo form_radio('person_type', 'karjoo', '', 'id=karjoo');
echo form_label('کارجــو', 'karjoo');
echo '</div>';

$('#signup_form').validate({errorElement:'span',
    errorClass:'signup_form_err',
    rules:{
        person_type:{
            required:true
        }
    messages:{
        person_type:{
            required:"لازمه"
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How are we supposed to debug something without the code?

Comment: oh! right. sorry. im update question. TNX!

Comment: @masoudamirian I think you missed }(closing bracket) of rules before message.

Comment: @PratikGadoya yes. when i copy code to here, missed. but in my project it right.